# Can we launch simulator or emulator on Android Studio only?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I am new to ionic2 and angular2.I have developed an application on ionic2 and angular2 in visual studio code editor.Now I want to debug(test) my apk with the simulator or emulator.I found on Android studio but make out that the code should be written in android studio code editor.Is there any other possibility to test on simulator or emulator.
Please let me know if more inputs are needed regarding this.

Comment: If you have `apk` then why not test that on a real device?

Comment: `ionic emulate android`?

Comment: @Sampath sometimes we need to test on different phone sizes, version, and etc.

Comment: Mobile app developer with an android device is not a miracle thing I guess.Maybe he doesn't know how to do that.Hope he'll give a feedback. @cricket_007

Comment: I have tested that apk on my android phone. But it is not working correctly.So i want to debug it. may be simulator or emulator can help me out.don't know.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use any IDE for emulator or you can even launch emulator stand alone from SDK manager directly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html), once you've added `Android` to your platform, you can just run these commands:

```
$ ionic build android
$ ionic emulate android
```

Comment: when I ran `$ ionic emulate android` the following error is displayed.
`Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1`. @Sakuto

Comment: A common solution to this is to remove Android and add it again. `ionic platform remove android` and `ionic platform add android`

Comment: The same error is displayed after following your instructions. @Sakuto

Comment: These are the results.
`BUILD SUCCESSFUL


Total time: 1 mins 55.515 secs

Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/Lenovo/walkin1/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk


ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1`
@Sakuto

Answer (score 0):

set up environment variable for ionic and android sdk to run command in shell or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1.)Connect the device to the machine abd run `ionic run android`.
                         OR
2.) Install app-ionic view from http://view.ionic.io, upload your application.And you can test your application very easily.